# pass value from ajax return to input field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to insert value data to each field input from ajax return ?

1. This is my input field

   ```
       <div class="form-group col-sm-2 ">
       <label>Barcode</label>
       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputBarcode" id="inputBarcode" />
           <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
           </span>                     
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-4 input-group-sm">
       <label>Nama Barang</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namaBarang" id="namaBarang" disabled/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-2 input-group-sm">
       <label>Satuan</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="satuanBarang" id="satuanBarang" disabled/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-2 input-group-sm">
       <label>Harga</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hargaBarang" id="hargaBarang" disabled/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-2 ">
       <label>Jumlah</label>
       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlahBarang" id="jumlahBarang" />
           <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">Add</button>
           </span>                     
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. This is my Ajax

   ```
   $('#inputBarcode').blur(function(){

       var noBarcode=$('#inputBarcode').val();

       $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url:'dataBarang.php',
          data:{barcode:noBarcode},

          success:function(response){
              $('#namaBarang').val(response);
          },

       });
   });
   ```
3. This is query from ajax triggered

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['barcode'])){

       $barcode=$_POST['barcode'];

       $qry=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM tbl_barang WHERE id_barang='$barcode' ");

       WHILE ($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){

           $namaBarang=$res['nama_barang'];
           $hargaNormal=$res['harga_jual_barang'];
           $qtyDiskon=$res['qty_diskon'];
           $hargaDiskon=$res['harga_qty_diskon'];

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What is the value of `response` in your ajax success callback?

Comment: as per your code you are not echo any think from php  so response wont be there

Comment: yes, response is success

Comment: if i echo at php code, the response is success

Comment: i want to get data from $namaBarang, $hargaNormal, $qtyDiskon, $hargaDiskon.and than insert to input field 1. <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namaBarang" id="namaBarang" disabled/> 2. <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hargaBarang" id="hargaBarang" disabled/> and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return JSON from PHP and decode at JS and place in INPUT FIELD

```
    if(isset($_POST['barcode'])){

$barcode=$_POST['barcode'];

$qry=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM tbl_barang WHERE id_barang='$barcode' ");
$arr_data=array();
WHILE ($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){

    $arr_data['namaBarang']=$res['nama_barang'];
    $arr_data['hargaNormal']=$res['harga_jual_barang'];
    $arr_data['qtyDiskon']=$res['qty_diskon'];
    $arr_data['hargaDiskon']=$res['harga_qty_diskon'];

}
echo json_encode($arr_data);
```

---

```
$('#inputBarcode').blur(function(){

    var noBarcode=$('#inputBarcode').val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'dataBarang.php',
       data:{barcode:noBarcode},

       success:function(response){
           var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
           $('#namaBarang').val(obj.namaBarang);
       },

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the code you created has been successful,  thanks.

Comment: This is working fine, good answer.